Relating the order of a polynomial to the resultant in the context of formal power series
I urgently need to understand how to begin or the complete proof of the following statement:$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}$
While reading the paper here on page one, in the introduction, the author provides the following definition:

$O(f,g)$ is defined to be the order of the $y$ resultant of $f$ and $g$ with respect to a fixed order in $\mathbb{N}^e$. That is, $
O(f,g) = O(\Res_y(f,g)).$

Here, $f$ and $g$ are polynomials in the ring $k[\![x_1, \ldots, x_e]\!][y]$, and it is given that $f$ does not divide $g$, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Now, suppose that $f$ is irreducible in $k[\![x_1, \ldots, x_e]\!][y]$ and is a quasi-ordinary polynomial. By the Abhyankar-Jung theorem, there exists a $y \in k[\![x_1^{1/n}, \ldots, x_e^{1/n}]\!]$ such that $f(x_1, \ldots, x_e, y) = 0$.
Later in the introduction, the author states that
$
O(f,g) = n O_x\left(g(x_1, \ldots, x_e, y)\right),
$
where $n = O_y(f)$ is the order of $f$ in $y$.
How can we prove this result, or how should we begin to approach the proof?

Why "urgently"? is it an assignment?

@YCor No, but I have tried many times and truly love learning about it.

Resultant and its Order: suppose $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_e)$.
The resultant $\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}\Res(f, g)$ is defined as the determinant of the Sylvester matrix formed by $f$ and $g$. It satisfies the following properties:
$$
\Res(f, g) = \prod_{\xi} g(x, y_\xi(x)),
$$
where the product runs over all roots $y_\xi(x)$ of $f(x, y)$ (including all conjugates under the Galois group of $K[\![x^{1/n}]\!]/k[\![x]\!]$).
Since $f(x, y)$ is irreducible and quasi-ordinary, it has $n$ roots $y_\xi(x)$ in $K[\![x^{1/n}]\!]$ thus:
$$
\text{Res}(f, g) = \prod_{\xi} g(x, y_\xi(x)).
$$
The order of $g(x, y_\xi(x))$ is the same as the order of $g(x, y(x))$, because the $y_\xi(x)$ are conjugates of $y(x)$ and $g(x, y)$ has coefficients in $k[\![x]\!]$.
Hence:
$$
\operatorname{\mathsf {Ord}}(\Res(f, g)) = \sum_{\xi}\operatorname{\mathsf {Ord}}(g(x, y_\xi(x))) = n \cdot \operatorname{\mathsf {Ord}}(g(x, y(x))).
$$
